How do we create soap:header in jax-rpc webservice?
Can anyone please help me to create soap:header in jax-rpc webservice
I am not seeing any example in jax-rpc.
I need step by step creation from java to wsdl and mapping files. Your guidance would be very helpful to me.. thanks
